# Fixed height on multiselect

Tags: html, css

As you can see on jsfiddle bellow, I'm using a vue component called Vue Multiselect.

When the text of a multiselect is bigger then its width, the height of the multiselect increases to fit the text.

I would like to maintain it in one line without increasing the height nor the width.

https://jsfiddle.net/uweL9zap/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <multiselect 
    v-model="value" 
    :options="options"
    track-by="library"
    :custom-label="customLabel"
    :option-height="50"
    >
  </multiselect>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
    data: {
    value: { language: 'JavaScript teste teste teste', library: 'Vue-Multiselect' },
    options: [
        {   language: 'JavaScript teste teste teste', library: 'Vue.js' },
      { language: 'JavaScript teste teste teste', library: 'Vue-Multiselect' },
      { language: 'JavaScript teste teste teste', library: 'Vuelidate' }
    ]
    },
  methods: {
    customLabel (option) {
      return `${option.library} - ${option.language}`
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Avenir', sans-serif;
}

.multiselect {
  width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply want to cut the text you could add the following `css`:

```
.multiselect__single {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

`white-space: nowrap` will avoid the line breaks and `overflow: hidden` just hides the overlapping text. The `wdith` and `height` of the select will stay the same as before.

Here you can see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/f7at84y6/